# Check if all dictionaries contain a specific key with a specific value

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to dive into the `['labels_detected_summary']` of `0, 1, 2` to figure out if all of their `['is_mode_unanimous']` keys are true.

I know that the `all()` function will help with checking the values at the end, but should I tap into these separate dictionaries with a `key, val` approach or some kind of `.get` or `iteritems()` ?

```
    "payload": {
            "0": {
                "labels_detected_summary": {"comm_mode": str, "is_mode_unanimous": bool, "is_mode_match_pred": bool},
                "labels_detected": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "1": {
                "labels_detected_summary": {"comm_mode": str, "is_mode_unanimous": bool, "is_mode_match_pred": bool},
                "labels_detected": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "labels_detected_summary": {"comm_mode": str, "is_mode_unanimous": bool, "is_mode_match_pred": bool},
                "labels_detected": {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: See, this is my problem with SO right now. I knew I didn't "post my code," but I also knew that people would have fun hacking on different aspects of this and that I would learn something. Zero chance I would have thought about using a key-accessing iterator. It's a good post that deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: _but should I tap into these separate dictionaries with a key, val approach or some kind of .get or iteritems()_ A loop, I guess?

Comment: @AMC yeah, just googling around about the proper way to work w built in dictionary methods

Comment: The `all` function itself is generally used with a generator expression, which does the iteration; the first part of that expression just needs to check if the current dictionary has "True" in the right place. You can use regular square bracket notation for that - `d['labels_detected_summary']['is_mode_unanimous']` does the trick, where `d` is your iteration variable.

Comment: @kaya3 okay, thanks! so something like `all( d['labels_detected_summary']['is_mode_unanimous'] == True )`?

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax You can omit the `== True`. If you ever did have to test whether something is True like that, you should use `is True`, not `==`.

Comment: `== True` is superfluous for a boolean value, but you need it to be generator expression - `... for d in payload.values()` for example. I suggest looking for a tutorial or reference on the `all()` function.

Comment: `all()` is testing every member evaluates to `True`

Comment: I have to run out the door, but thanks for pointing me to list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, if you are sure that all the keys are going to be present you can do:

```py
all(
    x['labels_detected_summary']['is_mode_unanimous'] for x in data['payload'].values()
)
```

If data might be incomplete you can use `.get(key, default)` so it doesn't raise a `KeyError` when it doesn't find it:

```py
all(
    x.get('labels_detected_summary', {}).get('is_mode_unanimous', False) for x in data.get('payload', {}).values()
)
```